# Analysis of damper having mass

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, anharmonic-oscillators

[image]

How to do analysis of a non ideal viscous damper (damper having mass)? How to find out an equivalent system for it?(having a ideal damper)

Answer (score 0):

Take the mass of the moving part of the damper and add it to the main mass on top. They’re rigidly linked, so the revised model is identical for this type of problem. Similarly, the nonmoving mass is rigidly connected to the ground, whose mass isn’t used in this type of problem.